# Using spark to spread data load in multiple computer

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Spark, and trying to understand its concepts clearly.

Assume that I'm having a very large dataset and around mega bytes of data are daily receiving my application. I need to spread the load of my data in many computers. Also, a rapid response to the new data are also required. Ex: send a message once a certain calculation done for that dataset.

How Spark is useful in this scenario.

Comment: Less than 1GB daily is really not that much data to warrant using Spark

Comment: Does this mean map reduce more suitable?

Comment: Not even that. Any modern database can handle that amount of data fine. Doesn't even need to be distributed. Plus, using a database will allow faster queries than Spark, MapReduce, or any Hadoop related tool would (except Hbase, perhaps)